# Гекльберри и транслитерация

Tags: транслитерация, переводы

Почему русская транслитерация английских (и латинских) слов не соответствует изначальным звукам?

Для примера приведу имя героя Марка Твена Гекльберри. По английски оно пишется Huckleberry, и читается Хаклбэри.

1) Г вместо Х - такая транслитерация существует и с греческой буквой ита (Н, η), и с латинской аш (Н, h). (Для сравнения: Гондурас, Гера, гармония) Оба звука произносятся более мягко, воздушно, чем русская Х, но ни чем не напоминают Г!

2) Несколько раз видела в переводах английских книг что "u" меняют на "е". U, u в английском может иметь разные оттенки, но такая транслитерация встречается когда она соответствует звуку А. Никак не пойму, в чём же провинилась буква А, что её так отсторонили от дела.

3) Е вместо Э. Присутствует почти во всех словах иностранного проишождения, где звук Э встречается в середине слова. Я пологаю, что это просто для того, чтобы читалось более "по русски", выглядело более комфортно, поскольку во многих случаях произносится всё равно Э. Но в некоторых, произношение тоже меняется - как в имени ГекльбЕрри.

4) Мягкий знак - не смотря на то, что в английском мягких согласных нет, мы частенько засовываем мягкие знаки между согласными. Возможно, для удобного произношения.

5) В английском отсутствует разница в произношении двойных согласных, но в переводах они сохраняются. Я пологаю, что это просто более удобная транскрипция.

Пожалуйста, объясните или подтвердите догадки!

Answer (score 1):

Простите, но ваши "догадки" сложно даже осмыслить.

Начнем с того, что передача слов (чаще всего - в отношении имен собственных) одного языка посредством алфавита другого называется транслитерацией, а не транскрипцией. Транскрипция - передача фонетики слова, она используется обычно для передачи произношения в языке-источнике.

> > > Для примера приведу имя героя Марка Твена Гекльберри. По английски оно пишется Huckleberry, и читается Хаклбэри.

Да, в английском примерно как Хаклбэри.

> > 1) Г вместо Х - такая транслитерация существует и с греческой буквой ита (Н, η),

Вас обманули.)))
Буква Н в греческом передает звук долгий звук И. В древнегреческом - Э.
Для Г в греческом есть гамма, для Х - хи.

> и с латинской аш (Н, h). (Для сравнения: Гондурас, Гера, гармония)

Давайте - мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно.
Начнем с греческого, чтобы о нем забыть раз и навсегда.

*В греческом письме применяются надстрочные знаки. Это знаки ударения:
  ´ - острое,
  ` - тупое,
  ῀ - облеченное;
и придыхания:
  ’ - тонкое
  ῾ - густое
Каждая начальная гласная или дифтонг имеют знак придыхания. Тонкое придыхание при чтении не произносится, а густое произносится как латинское "h" или украинское "г": ὄρος "oros" ἱστορία "historia". *

В слове Гера  Ἥρα - впереди идет густое придыхание (дасия) в сочетании с острым ударением (оксия), это сочетание передается латинским Hh, соответствующим русскому Гг (почему так - ниже).

> Оба звука произносятся более мягко, воздушно, чем русская Х, но ни чем не напоминают Г!

С греческим вопрос снят. Остался латинский. Латинское Hh примерно соответствует немецкому - это простой, но энергичный выдох. В некоторых романских языках он превратился в совсем слабый выдох, в других и вовсе исчез. Сравнивать лучше всего именно с немецким. Так вот немецкое Hh в славянских более всего напоминает оглушенное украинское или южнорусское Гг. Это не совсем точная аналогия, но все-таки достаточно близкая. Когда-то таким было Г и в русском языке, по крайней мере - как один из фонетических вариантов. Поэтому, когда перед учеными встала необходимость подобрать букву для передачи латинского (он же - немецкий) звука Hh, выбирать можно было из двух - Х и Г. Оба эти звука отличались от иноязычного образца, но Г было все-таки ближе по параметрам положения речевых органов, хотя и отличалась от "образца" звонкостью. В то время как Х было тоже глухим, но далеким по принципу звукоизвлечения. Неудивительно, что было выбрано Гг. Произошло это, думается не ранее в XV-XVI века. До того писали в основном ориентируясь на греческий или вообще как Бог душу положит.

(+)-------

> 2) Несколько раз видела в переводах английских книг что "u" меняют на "е". U, u в английском может иметь разные оттенки, но такая транслитерация встречается когда она соответствует звуку А. Никак не пойму, в чём же провинилась буква А, что её так отсторонили от дела.

При предложении английских имен собственных чаще всего придерживаются традиции, предписывающей следовать графическому образу слова, ибо английская фонетика и особенно его соответствие правописанию - не для слабонервных. Поскольку английский стал по-настоящему популярным языком международного общения не ранее второй половины XIX века, а проникновение имен началось гораздо раньше, то не удивительно, что письменная традиция закрепилась.
Это объясняет почти все особенности графического воспроизведения английских имен. Впрочем, современные переводчики часто от неё отходят в сторону приближения к фонетике.

(+)-------

> 3) Е вместо Э. Присутствует почти во всех словах иностранного происхождения, где звук Э встречается в середине слова. Я полагаю, что это просто для того, чтобы читалось более "по-русски", выглядело более комфортно, поскольку во многих случаях произносится всё равно Э. Но в некоторых, произношение тоже меняется - как в имени ГекльбЕрри.

Э в русском языке традиционно употребляется только в начале слова и в некоторых коротких иностранных словах, в основном - для смыслоразличения. Не вижу необходимости отступать от этого правила для передачи имен собственных, кроме разве некоторых особых случаев.

(+)-------

> 4) Мягкий знак - не смотря на то, что в английском мягких согласных нет, мы частенько засовываем мягкие знаки между согласными. Возможно, для удобного произношения.

Примеры? 
Единственное, что приходит на ум - мягкое Л, в слове джентльмен и именах собственных. Это тоже традиция, она имеет очень ограниченную область действия и основывается на том, 
как *произносятся* эти слова в *русском*.

(+)-------

> 5) В английском отсутствует разница в произношении двойных согласных, но в переводах они сохраняются. Я полагаю, что это просто более удобная транскрипция.

Вот это, пожалуй единственный актуальный вопрос из всех поднятых.
Здесь действительно нагромождение правил и рекомендаций, иногда взаимоисключающих, иногда просто нежизнеспособных... И ко всему - часто меняющихся.
Тему эту я тут не подниму. Если очень кратко - сейчас стараются соблюсти баланс между русской фонетикой (т.е. сохранять удвоение там, где в русском это удвоение возможно)  и иностранным написанием. Так конечные удвоения обычно не поддерживаются (за исключением ЛЛ), а "внутренние" завязываются правила языка-источника. Но это только первый слой. Есть масса обоснованных и не очень исключений в обеих позициях.

> Пожалуйста, объясните или подтвердите догадки!

Ну уж как мог... Старайтесь все-таки расчленять вопросы... Это ж совершенно разные случаи, одному человеку ответить на все тяжко.

Comment: Конечно, транслитерация. :) Я до этого читала вопрос про транскрипцию, и оно само вылезло. Я сразу поправила, как заметила.

Всё таки непонятно, почему традиционно А/У сделалось Е. Тут ни графического образа, ни фонетики.

Насчёт Э/Е, я не говорю что надо менять правило, мне просто интересно откуда оно взялось.

Comment: Просто для примера, имена с мягким знаком германского проишождения: Ральф, Рудольф. Или же Меттью (вместо Меттъю, что больше соответсвует английскому произношению). Фамилии, заканчиваюшиеся на -ville тоже кончаются на мягкий знак; это правда по вине французского, откуда и пришли все эти фамилии - там и правда мягкая л. Но мягкий знак у нас остался по привычке и в теперь уже английских фамилиях, которые по английски произносятся с твёрдой л.

Про придыхания в греческом раньше не знала, спасибо. Многое объясняет. :)

Comment: После Б там шва, она немягкая, этим действительно Э более оправдана. В самом слове berry E под ударением, мягкость появляется (по крайней мере в британском RP). Уверен, что вы это понимаете, написал для других. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Транслитерация латинского **h**(а вследствие и его новоевропейских аналогов) как Г, а **ch** как Х идёт с украинских и белорусских земель, по польскому образцу (в польском языке есть звуки Х и Г(укр) и Г(рус), записываемые как **ch, h и g** соответственно). Естественно, книжники транслитерировали их, опираясь на привычное им произношение кириллических букв, то есть как Х, Г и КГ(искусственное КГ для обозначения "русского" Г вскоре утратило смысл, так как большинство читателей все равно произносили его как Г "украинское", таким образом два столь разных звука, как **h** и **g**, стали транслитерироваться одинаково, через "Г").
В связи с присоединением восточных земель Речи Посполитой к Московскому Царству, Россия получила огромный приток европейски-образованных книжников, механически перенесших эту нелогичную для России традицию транслитерации в зарождающийся русский литературный язык. В XVIII-XIX веках делались попытки писать по-иному, но традиция была уже слишком сильна, в двадцатом веке английская транслитерация таки сменилась более естественной(помогло отсутствие в английском аналога нашего "Х" — место было свободно), а в немецком ситуация в целом мало изменилась(так как там есть и "ch" и "h").

**2)** По современным правилам "Э" и "Е" передают разные звуки английского языка, но вряд ли автор транслитерации "Гекльберри" руководствовался подобными соображениями, просто с "Е" звучит "попроще".

**3)** Английское и немецкое L — альвеолярное, то есть язык отталкивается от дёсен. Русское твёрдое "Л" — от зубов, мягкое "ЛЬ" — от дёсен(проверьте сами), так что выбор мягкого "ЛЬ" в транслитерации логичен. Вспомните также передачу акцента русских немцев Гоголя и др. авторов 19 века — там сплошное "ЛЬ" - *слушаль, пользаль* и т.д.